# Isolating I2C device behind a switch

Tags: switches, i2c, temperature, isolation

I have a piece of closed hardware (proprietary) that has one I2C port. On this port I have two devices, one that requires constant 5 V for counting and the other is a temperature/humidity sensor (also proprietary). The issue I have is that the temperature/humidity sensor is experiencing a self heating due to the constant 5 V applied to the counting device. Is it possible to put another I2C device, a switch, in front of the temperature/humidity sensor to isolate it from the constant 5 V and only power it up when a reading is necessary?

Comment: regulate voltage or current to the temp/humidity sensor to limit it to what it will operate properly at or you could just use a mosfet on a discrete.

Comment: Yes it is possible. But, will the I2C controlled switch experience self-heating, too, or is your plan to place it far from the temp/humidity sensor? Also, are you sure you cannot somehow suspend the temp/humidity sensor using commands sent over I2C?

Comment: If the temp/humidity sensor is not proprietary, please edit your question to include the manufacturer and model and maybe a link to the datasheet.

Comment: @mkeith I would locate the switch a good distance from the sensor.

Comment: I think I would use an I2C bus switch and just control it with an IO pin from the closed hardware. If that is not possible, then you can use an I2C IO expander + the I2C bus switch. You can't just disconnect power from the temp/humidity sensor. You also need to isolate the I2C signals from the sensor at the same time you kill the power to it. Or before you kill the power to it.

Comment: why does the temp&hum sensory has no reset/shutdown/low power mode?

Comment: @christian-b The configuration of the hardware in this case is using a splitter, the manufacturer initially didn't intend on multiple devices being connected to this port. The other device must have constant 5v, there's no means to isolate the sensor on the other side of the splitter.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you, this is what I was hoping would be the solution. I can control a bus switch via scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be easily possible but fishy using a multiway analog SPST switch like ADG715. Just make sure to cut all the linces as already mentioned. Else the unpowered IC might pull your I2C lines down.